# In Nitrous.io how do you delete a tab indent?

Tags: nitrousio

In other IDEs you can delete a tab indent (i.e. the space created by hitting the tab key) by selecting Shift-Tab

This doesn't seem to work in Nitrous.io - does anyone know how to delete the tab indent?

The only way I can see is to hit the back key multiple times which is time-consuming and doesn't keep the tab indents aligned line-by-line.